# Administrative country boundaries over the years

Tags: vector, borders, natural-earth

I am using natural earth's [Admin 0 Countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/) dataset and it works great, but need to plot some data going back to 1962. Any idea how I could handle the [national border changes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_border_changes_since_World_War_I)? (In fact, I only need base maps for 1962, 1988 and 2014.)

Comment: What do you mean 'handle'? You would need to obtain additional data (e.g. shapefiles) for each one of those years you are interested in. Subsequently, assuming you want a static map, you could do a simple symbology to apply different color to different borders

Comment: Yes my question is how/where to obtain those additional shapefiles.

Comment: For open data you could try the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

This "CShapes" dataset seems to have what you need - historical border data from 1945-2015. It is available as a Shapefile download and as a KML: 
http://nils.weidmann.ws/projects/cshapes.html. It has also been visualized in [this](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline) Leaflet plugin.

From the readme:
  *This is a GIS dataset of country boundaries, incorporating changes in the 
period 1946-2015. The list of states is compatible with the 
"Correlates of War" system membership list, version 2011.1, 
and the Gleditsch and Ward (1999) list of independent states. 
The dataset provides information about the core territories of 
the given states, and excludes colonies and other dependent 
territories. The changing boundaries of the international system 
are represented in the dataset by coding a "lifetime" 
for each polygon, i.e. a start and end date between which the polygon is valid.*

**Screenshot (1962)**:
[image: 1962]